# Find CSS selector for popup menu item for Selenium in Python 3

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, firefox

I'm attempting to make a DeviantART Llamabot for a friend as my first Selenium project with Python 3. I have the bot 99% working except for being able to find the "give llama" button.

The problem seems to be that the menu the button appears under is a popup and I can't just right click and select "copy css selector" in Firefox. As soon as I inspect the element for the give menu the menu closes and the html changes.

I've managed to take a screen shot of a random sample page of the code so I can even see what's there. I've tried learning how CSS selectors work from scratch myself and I've managed to find every nested element EXCEPT the actual items in the list. I've tried looking for Nth child and using the ">" operator. I've attempted searching by class name, name, Xpath, link name, partial link name, nothing has worked.

I've read about this problem inspecting popup elements elsewhere and the suggestions are effectively to write an HTML parser or something to copy the entire html code as it changes and then select it from your copy. I'm not going to do that for this project. It's entirely too much work unless I absolutely have to for some reason.

Honestly at this point I don't even care anymore and I just want someone to outright just tell me what to type in so I can finish this project. This is the screenshot I managed to get. I'm looking for the item highlighted in blue.

[image]

Since my code was requested for clarification here it is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

Deviant = browser.get("http://www.deviantart.com/random/deviant")
GiveMenu = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".i47")
GiveMenu.click()
#GiveLlama = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("")`
```

Everything except the last line works which is why the last line is commented out until I can figure out what to put in there. No matter what I've tried, including the examples provided by the people answering this question so far, I either get a no such element error or an illegal syntax error.

Comment: I suggest breaking your question into paragraphs, as it is a little hard to read. Also, copy and paste all your code , which relates to your question, directly in your question.

Comment: I don't understand. You're looking for the item highlighted in blue? Its CSS selector is right there at the bottom of your Firefox inspector, and it has the class `.givellama`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath selector, in chrome you can use rigth click and click on copy > copy Xpath, or the element selected on your inspector is "div.popup2 .blockmenu a.f.givellama"

Answer (score 0):

You should click the "Give" button first, when the pop up dialog opens, inspect the "Give a Llama Badge" element and identify the xpath. Here is a screen shot.

[screen shot to locate "Give a Llama Badge" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V33AK.png)

You can find that, the xpath to locate "Give a Llama Badge" button(Should click the Give button first to locate this element).

```
//a[@class='f givellama']
```

The xpath to locate "Give button"

```
//a[@href='#give-give-give']/span[text()='Give']
```

As you pointed out, when the popup dialog opens, if you try to test the xpath in the browser console via "Firepath" or others, when you type "Enter" or click the left mouse, the popup windows is closed. But don't worry about this, since you already identified the xpath locator, you can debug it in your scripts.

Comment: Thank you, I thought i was already using Firebug and Firepath but I was mistaken. This appeared to work. It's still giving me a nu such element error but that might be because I need to put in a wait of some kind to guarantee the elements have loaded.

Comment: @Shoopdeboop sounds good. When developing selenium scripts, if the xpath locator is correct and validated via Firebug, if there still is 'no such element' error, just think about the browser loading time. I usually call a 'wait for element' to avoid the loading issue.

Comment: I got it to work, it clicks what I want it to click, now I'm just adding the rest of the code to make it a usable tool for them. Thanks for your help.